Design Automation not export .sat file
I have a problem with exporting an autodesk revit .sat file using design automation. If I run it inside Revit on desktop, there is no problem. but the same code does not work from Design automation. I have tried to export it directly from a Revit project and also from the family edition but to no avail, the export only appears false.
I would like to mention that this problem does not happen when exporting fbx, ifc, dwfx, etc.
I have been use this method
View3D view3D = new FilteredElementCollector(document)
    .OfClass(typeof(View3D))
    .Cast<View3D>()
    .FirstOrDefault(v => v.Name == "3D_View");

ICollection<ElementId> view3Ds = new List<ElementId>() { view3D.Id };

try
{
    SATExportOptions SATOptions = new SATExportOptions();
    bool isExported = document.Export(desktopPath, $"Files.sat", view3Ds , SATOptions);
    TaskDialog.Show("Export Sin transaction" , isExported ? "(*) SAT Modelo exportado correctamente" : "(X) SAT Error al exportar modelo");
    //transaction.Commit();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    TaskDialog.Show("Title",$"(X) Error al Exportar .sat {ex.Message}");
}


I have consulted with the Revit Design Automation Engineering team regarding your inquiry.
It appears that the Revit 2022 Design Automation does not support SAT export functionality.
However, I am pleased to inform you that this issue has been addressed in the Revit 2023 Design Automation version.
Therefore, I kindly request that you consider utilizing Revit 2023 Design Automation for your requirements.
Furthermore, the Engineering team has conveyed that at present, there are no imminent plans to incorporate SAT export support into Revit 2022 Design Automation.
